# QFileDialog::setNameFilter only show files with no extension

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

In my project I open a `QFileDialog` to have the user select a file to open. The file I'm expecting does not have an extension. I would like to set a filter that only shows files that don't have any extension.

Currently, I filter out any files that don't have the exact name:

```
QString path;
QString desktopPath = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DesktopLocation).at(0);
path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Select File"), desktopPath + "\\DATAFILE", tr("DATAFILE file (DATAFILE)"));
```

However, in the case where the file might be renamed (for example, `DATAFILE (2)`) that file wouldn't show up because the name doesn't match exactly.

Filtering it to accept all files is not what I want either because that would allow any file type to be selected.

Any suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try `"DATAFILE*"` as alternative name filter?

Comment: @Scheff Why not put it as an answer?  `"DATAFILE file (DATAFILE*)"` should be the right way.

Comment: @Jiu I was not really sure and had no code at hand to check it out. Additionally, I'm uncertain whether native file dialogs (we use exclusively via `QFileDialog`s static functions) and Qt file dialogs behave exactly equal. So, I made it a question to provide at least an idea to the OP. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I tried just now, it did work well.

Comment: So, I would enjoy to read your answer to this question. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't this require the file names to begin with DATAFILE? The idea is to accept any file name, as long as they don't have any extension. And not accept it if it has an extension